# How to build cdt-9.3.0 source code?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I build cdt-9.3.0 source code with "mvn package" command, but failed with some message like "org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be fount". Does the build method wrong or some useful suggesion ? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the [CDT mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/cdt-dev).